# How to print an string without the newline Mips Assembly language

Tags: mips

I am trying to get the output in the same line with the result(string). I have found examples, but none of them explained the process. I know that the string has to be store in memory and then access it through bit by bit, but I got lost in the process.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your name: "
name: .space 101

result: .asciiz " ...that's the name"
.text
.globl main

main:
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, name # Get the input
    li $v0, 8
    li $a1,101
    syscall

    la $a0, name # print the result
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, result
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: To eliminate the requirement for the user to hit return to enter the string, you will have to read one character at a time (syscall 12) and build the string yourself, character by character, if you want a full string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from that, when you read in the input the new line will be read also, so it has to be removed in order to achieve your needs.

This is one way to do it:

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your name: "
name: .space 101

result: .asciiz " ...that's the name"
.text
.globl main

main:
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, name # Get the input
    li $v0, 8
    li $a1,101
    syscall

    addi $t1, $t1, 0 # len = 0
len_to_new_line:
    lb $t2, ($a0) # t2 = *a0
    beq $t2, '\n', end # if t2 == '\n' -> stop
    addi $t1, $t1, 1 # len++
    addi $a0, $a0, 1 # a0++
    b len_to_new_line   
end:
    la $a0, name 
    add $a0, $a0, $t1 
    sb $zero, ($a0) # overwrite '\n' with 0

    la $a0, name # print the result
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, result
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Output

```
Enter your name: David
David ...that's the name
```

**EDIT:** The len is not even needed and code can be reduced to this (only the changed part)

```
len_to_new_line:
    lb $t2, ($a0) # t2 = *a0
    beq $t2, '\n', end # if t2 == '\n' -> stop
    addi $a0, $a0, 1 # a0++
    b len_to_new_line   
end:
    sb $zero, ($a0) # overwrite '\n' with 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying to fully understand the main idea after you get to the end block, you load the address again, and add the "len" which put you at the end of the word, but when you were in the previous block of  code you exit before get to the "\n", So the len would be a position before the "\n", then you overwrite the end with a 0, but you load the name again, why you didn't get the "\n" again at the end after you load the name. I just trying to understand the process. Again thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @DanielMendozaPupo Glad if it helped. Well your question made me realize that the whole `len` and the reloading of the `name` are pointless since when the `len_to_new_line` loop exit `a0` will points to the new line character already so the code can be reduced to the one I put on the edited section. I hope that make it more clear also since shorter, more logical.

Comment: I am grateful for the help and the quick response. You help me to understand this process.